# "swipe up to load more" - opposite of refresh control "pull to refresh"

Tags: react-native

With react-native's `FlatList` and `refreshControl` we are able to accomplish the "pull-to-refresh" feature when we "swipe down" as seen here:

gfycat screencast: https://gfycat.com/GoodCarefreeKitty

However my goal is to ALSO accomplish a "swipe up" as seen here:

gfycat screencast: https://gfycat.com/MenacingFaithfulAustraliancurlew

Is there a built in like `refreshControl` for this "swipe up"?

I am targeting Android, and was trying to detect over scroll but Android doesn't have overscroll on lists.

Comment: Not out of the box but you can use [`onEndReached`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached) and [`onEndReachedThreshold`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreachedthreshold)

Comment: Ah `onEndReachThreshold` in combintation with `onEndReached` is very interesting thank you @bennygenel! The default value does not seem to be documented, is it `0`?

Comment: I don't know the default number but `onEndReached` returns distance as a parameter. You can easily implement and can see the default number. I'm glad if its gonna help.

Comment: Thanks @bennygenel I will try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use onEndReached function on flatlist (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached)

You can show spinner and send get request in onEndReached function.

Comment: while I was hoping for a built in, I'll accept this solution, thanks!

Comment: when I tried this onEndReached thing is is funky, i am having some usability issues. (1) I use flat list, and I put loader in footer. The footer doesnt show until "onEndReached" so the scroll is not so fluid. In other words  The scroll ends sharply, then "onEndReached" triggers showing "loading" then they see "scroll bar gets some more room" then they see "oh i can scroll now to see loader". (2) if after load there is no more data, it shows loader then finds no data then unides loader and `onEndReached` triggers again, this loops endlessly if left at bottom scroll. Any advices here sir?

Comment: Destroy after each addition :
``loadMore() {this.setState(prevState => ({
  arrayvar: [...prevState.arrayvar, appendData], loaderVisiblity: false
})}``

Comment: Thank you sir I will try this approach!!